# Same level in toctree and navigation bar with separated files

Tags: python-sphinx, navigationbar, toctree

I want to separate my files hierarchy from my document hierarchy, I want to have four sections of the same level in different files, two in the same file and two in separated files, at the end i want the toctree refer to them in the same level.

**main.rst**

```
main
====


section 1
---------
something


section 2
---------
something


.. toctree::

    section3
    section4
```

**section3.rst**

```
section 3
---------
something
```

**section4.rst**

```
section 4
---------
something
```

With this code i have this result:

[image]

And this

[image]

But i want it to be in the same level, i want this result:

[image]

And this

[image]

In my case, the two first sections are small but the other are too long and i want them to be on their own file (and also in their own page when browsing so `include` is not a solution for me) and conserve the document hierarchy when browsing.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

try put a **_ref** tag before the toctree in main.rst

```
.. _ref-section3:
.. toctree::
   section3

.. _ref-section4:
.. toctree::
   section4
```